# SearchView by EditText android

Tags: android, searchview

I want to implement searchView like this [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-search-to-your-apps/) and [link2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) but I want to make a search from own EditText not in ActioBar or in menu.

I want to know what is the code in the main layout xml file. consider that I'm not want to use ActionBar with menu item because it isn't supported for api less that level 11, I want to use the search and get result in the same Activity, all what I want to know how can I get the search bar when press a button to give it a word t search in sqlite and get the result in the same Activity?

Hope anyone got my mean. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the SearchView anywhere you want to. Why do you need/want to use an EditText?

Comment: Ok, I want example in xml layout, and Is searchView will work with the code in the links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a EditText, it is much easier to use a SearchView. If you don't want to have search interface in the action bar, then you can use a search widget, which is an instance of SearchView.

The basics are here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: Its the good tutorial but I want to know what is the code in the main layout xml file. consider that I'm not want to use ActionBar with menu item because it isn't supported for api less that level 11, I want to use the search and get result in the same Activity, all what I want to know how can I get the search bar when press a button ?

Comment: You can use the ActionBar on older devices if you use ActionBarCompat (or ActionBarsherlock).

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want the ActionBar *and* have to support older API levels than API level 11 (Honeycomb) *and* do not want to use a search dialog, **you have to do everything on your own**.

You could use a `AutoCompleteTextView` to display search suggestions and start an activity / fragment to display a list of results with the query entered whenever the user triggers your search. That's not different from any other Activity that has to react to user input.

But **I strongly suggest to use ActionBarCompat and the support library to provide an ActionBar on older devices and use the SearchView within the ActionBar**. That's what users expect nowadays anyway and it makes development that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a search box using EditText (not in Action Bar), you may refer to the following XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Search...."
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But, I would suggest use ActionBar for the search box, it would look neat and easier as well. For search box using ActionBar, you may refer the following link:

http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/